# User control for Wordpress multisite

Tags: wordpress, multisite

I'm working on a Wordpress multisite project, if a user is registered on a site and the same user wants to register on another site, the user can't be created because  already exists. This is a big issue for me because each site must be work independently and users should to be created on each site.

Comment: Then why are you using a multisite system, and not keep them as completely separate websites?

Comment: Because there are plugins that only work with multisite.

Comment: Am I missing something here? That's one of the points of using a multisite setup, to only have to register on one site, and make that user account accessible on the other sites. Is the multisite managed via a plugin? By the way, your question isn't really a question either.. and is very, VERY vague. You should update it with some examples of what you've tried to fix, along with any other info, code or links.. or prepare to be downvoted.

Comment: no, the multisite not being managed by a plugin

Comment: So how is it managed? It might help if you talk to someone who knows more about the multisite setup? We're not going to be able to really help you due to the lack of information at the moment.

Comment: I got the solution now. I can use prefixes for user fields for each site. I had a issue and if you can't help just let to do negative comments! Thanks.

Comment: that comment didn't make sense, but I do hope you weren't implying I was leaving negative comments..? If you need to ask a question on here, your question will need to include ALOT more information in future, or you won't really get anywhere. This is a debugging website, not a general information forum. I'm just trying to help you.